Attack tag names?

There are two attack tags in plural (side-channel-attacks and timing-attacks). Those should probably be renamed?
The tags distinguisher and distinguishing-attack are very overlapping, I think. Do they require distinct tags or should they be merged? (Perhaps with some attack tags sprinkled in.)
cache-timing-attack seems so specific that I suggested it as a synonym of the more general timing-attacks. Feel free to agree or disagree here.


Nice findings – thanks for keeping an eye on the tags! Took care of 1 and 3. Didn’t have time to dive into 2 though…

IMHO for 2 I would merge them. :/

From a conceptual viewpoint, a distinguisher is a tool used within a distinguisher attack, so it makes some sense to keep them both. However the distinguisher is only ever relevant if you consider such attacks, so I'm for merging [tag:distinguisher] into [tag:distinguish-attack]

Since 1. and 3. are already taken care of by @e-sushi, that only leaves 2., i.e.the tags distinguisher/distinguishing-attack. Having taken a look at the tag wikis and questions, I think the latter should be made a synonym of the former. I cannot suggest this as I lack the relevant reputation.
The tag wiki should probably be mostly taken from distinguishing-attack, since it seems more developed. (Excerpt might need to be rewritten.)

+1 Done – guess it’s time for a “self-accept”. ;)
